# Triggered Send Errors In SFMC- How to access error data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, triggered-send

[image]

How to retrieve errored data of count 2 which is shown in image

Thanks in advance,
Raghuram.G

Comment: Does this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288899/monitoring-triggered-send-errors?rq=1 answer your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to get this information is from Support or Proactive Monitoring (Which will send you an email on the error if it 'breaks' your trigger message).

Now, trying to get this information from Support is a long and arduous process usually because honestly, that is not what they are really there to handle. You can talk with your account rep to see if they can build you a custom report ($$$) for it, but from everyone I have talked to they have said it is not possible.

To debug these errors (if it breaks the Trigger), usually what I do is look at the last sent record in send preview (assuming your Trigger Send DE pulls in ALL your fields/data) and see if it tosses any errors. Once you resolve those errors, you can then republish your trigger and restart it.

If its an error that did not break the trigger, then what I would do is compare the Trigger Send Definition vs the subscribers that are listed as 'sent' for that Trigger (Tracking tab, DataView, Extract, etc). This will not be the full picture of exactly which ones errored as this will also include those excluded from list detective, etc. in it - but will greatly reduce the number returned. To further reduce it, you can include a date of send in the Trigger Send Definition and then when you pull and compare, only do so in the appropriate date range.

Comment: How to get queued data from triggered send if it structed and data in queue?

Comment: @raghuramgowlikar - this should help: https://gortonington.com/alert-for-your-triggered-send-queue-limits-in-sfmc/

Comment: I need values through SSJS or SQL or AMP Script

Comment: @RaghuramGowlikar - not sure why you removed the accepted answer, but as I stated in my answer, there is no way to gather error info outside of SF Support or Proactive Monitoring. And if you are referring to the link I have in my comments, this is all in SSJS, which is what you requested in your most recent comment. I am not sure what else I can provide you here...

Comment: As @gortonington suggested we can refer:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_alert_manager.htm&type=5